# Isotope : Sorting and masonry layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

When I sort items of varying heights and then apply the masonry layout, the sorting breaks, because masonry rearranges the items. Here's a quick fiddle up of what I mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ahrengot/vxXg3/30/

The code used :

```
var isotope = $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.box',
    getSortData: {
        customValue : function ($el) {
            return $el.data('value');
        }
    }
});

$('#sort').on('click', function(e) {
    isotope.isotope({ 
        sortBy: 'customValue', 
        sortAscending: true
    });
});
```

If you click the "Sort items" button and look at the 3rd row you'll see the boxes sorted "seven, six eight" instead of "Six, seven eight".

unfortunately the fork Masonry Ordered http://masonry-ordered.tasuki.org/ is outdated, so is there is solution please

Comment: It looks like the height of the middle column is a little higher in the 3rd row and later on. This could be why the lowest value of the row is being placed here.

Comment: yes, I want to handle sorting of items with varying heights

Comment: Masonry-ordered is for the library masonry.js, not for isotope's masonry layout Mode.

Comment: If you want to use isotope v2, you can try this [plugin](https://github.com/michieldewit/isotope-modulo-columns). May be the closest you can get with the  masonry layout since it is actually doing what it is supposed to with varying heights.

Comment: I have tried your plugin but it does not work, thank you anyway for the suggestion

Comment: Varying heights are difficult. You run into the same problem described here in my answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052151/isotope-trying-to-sort-items-by-original-order/29088587#29088587

Comment: The plugin is for v2 of isotope, not the version you are using. Your main problem is that isotope's masonry layout is designed to layout items like a brick wall (hence "masonry"), i.e., it fits items in where they will fit best, not in specific order. There are other isotope layouts that will layout in order.